# document.cloneNode(true) doesn't clone user inputs

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use `document.cloneNode(true)` to clone/make a copy of an existing html page containing forms. When I am serialising it to a string, the string doesn't include user inputs.

I have a js script embedded in a html page with form and am trying to use `document.cloneNode(true)` to clone that page, serialise it, and save it in a s3 bucket. When user clicks on submit button the js function runs to clone the html page.

Issue is that the cloneNode() doesn't include the user inputs while cloning the HTML page. I checked the docs - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode but didn't find the handling of this use case.

Is this behaviour of cloneNode() expected? If so how can I achieve my requirement of having the user inputs like this -

```
<input type='text' value='John Doe'>
```

instead of

```
<input type='text'>
```

Do I have to manually set the value in every input field? There can be different types of inputs like checkbox, dates, etc so I think there should be a better way to achieve this.

Comment: To be clear here: You're cloning the document, then *serializing* it to HTML (for instance, with `innerHTML` or `outerHTML` or similar) and storing that text in an S3 bucket, right? And you're wondering why the `value` attribute in the HTML doesn't match the user input?

Comment: Yes that's correct. During serialisation the user inputs aren't getting captured

Comment: I am using this to serialise - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer/serializeToString

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of an `input` element is not reflected in its `value` attribute (or any other), despite the name. The `value` attribute provides the *default value* of an input, not its current value, even though the `value` *property* of an `HTMLInputElement` instance does give you the current value. This is one of the confusing things about the DOM. Here's the breakdown:

| Item | Attribute | Property |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Default value | `value` | `defaultValue` |
| Current value | *none* | `value` |

If you want an HTML string that captures the user's current input text on `input` elements (and their currently-selected items on `select` elements), you'll have to implement that functionality yourself, perhaps with `data-*` attributes.

Here's a quick-and-dirty example for `input` elements:

```js
// Respond to the `input` event by updating an attribute on the
// input element
document.addEventListener("input", ({target}) => {
    if (target instanceof HTMLInputElement) {
        target.setAttribute("data-current-value", target.value);
    }
});

// Hook up the button to show the HTML:
document.querySelector("[value='Show HTML']").addEventListener("click", () => {
    for (const input of document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]")) {
        console.log(input.outerHTML);
    }
});
```

```html
A: <input type="text" name="a">
<br>
B: <input type="text" name="b">
<br>
<div><input type="button" value="Show HTML"></div>
```

In that example, I grab the values as they change, but you could do it just before cloning the document as well.